# Scenario to get "add" event type/X-Goog-Resource-State in Google Drive PUSH Notification

Tags: push-notification, google-drive-api

I am trying to apply watch on a folder on Google Drive to get notification when any file has been added inside it. As per Google Drive documentation (https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push) the event type  (X-Goog-Resource-State)  should be "add" : "A new resource was created or shared." Instead I am getting X-Goog-Resource-State/event type as "update" when I am adding file inside watched folder. Please let me know which scenario will give me "add" event type/X-Goog-Resource-State.﻿

Comment: You may want to check the sample POST request for *Object Addition, Update, or Deletion* in [Notification Event Message Types](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification#_Notification_Types) wherein it was stated that, a notification event will be sent when a new object is added to a bucket, an existing object's content or metadata has been modified or an object is deleted from a bucket. As mentioned, the notification will be sent as a POST request to the configured application URL.

Comment: Any luck? Been trying to figure out how to receive File & Folder creation events for months

Comment: Any luck on achieving this? 'X-Goog-Resource-State' is always set to 'change' for me. It doesn't take into account the type of action performed inside the watched google drive directory.